# PHP array comparing

Tags: php, arrays, web, compare

I want to compare two arrays in php. I don't want to do it overall, but block by block.
kind of like this

```
if (a[1] == b[1]){ // do something }
if (a[2] == b[2]){ // do more }
```

how can i do this without a whole bunch of `ifs` ?

thanks in advance :)

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 5);
$b = array(1, 1, 1, 1);
$c = array('something', 'something', 'and so forth');
foreach($a as $key => $value){
   if($value == $b[$key]){
      echo $c[$key]. '<br />';
    }
}
```

my answer. compare 2 arrays, then rune some code. triggered by the blocks that match

Comment: is it intended to run a different block of code every time for each matching case (ie one match case triggers some filesystem calls, another match triggers some database calls, etc)?  Or run the same block of code every time?

Comment: clever question! I want to echo something different for each block. also, somethimes more than one block has to be run

Answer (score 1):

want to compare whole array element one by one  (assuming both array of same length)

```
foreach($a as $key => $value){
   if($value == $b[$key])
   {
     // do something
   }
   else
   {
     break;  // stop doing something and break
   }
}
```

if want to compare some keys

```
$keys = array('key1', 'key2');
foreach($keys as $value){
   if($a[$value] == $b[$value])
   {
     // true
   }
   else
   {
     // false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof(a);$i++){
  if(a[$i]==b[$i]){
    //DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(1, 3 , 5 ,6 , 7);
$b = array(3, 1, 5, 6, 8 ,9);
$array_size = min(count($a), count($b));

for ($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++) {
   if ($a[$i] == $b[$i]) { //you could/should check whether the index is present. 
    //some code
   }
}
```

This only works for arrays with the same uniformly distributed numerical index.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach(array_intersect_assoc($a,$b) as $key => $data)){
     switch($key){
         case 1:
             //something
             break;
         case 2:
             //something
             break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($a) && $i < count($b); ++$i) {
    if ($a[$i] == $b[$i]){
      // this is true
    } else {
      // this is false
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `if($a[$i] == $b[$i])`

Answer (score 0):

A good ol for loop should do the trick. You can start with an array of things to do:

```
$arrayOfThingsToDo = array( "someFunc", "anotherFunc", "yetAnotherFunc" );
$arrayOfA = array( "one", "two", "three" );
$arrayOfB = array( "one", "not two", "three" );

function doCompare($a, $b, $f) {
   $len = count($a);
   for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
      if($a[$i] == $b[$i]) {
         $f[$i]();
      }
   }
}
```

Good luck!